# Grouping transactions with Python / connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

With the Python / mysql cursor/connection API, I'm used to calling myConnection.commit() before closing the cursor.  I'd like to start using myConnection.rollback() at various strategic points, except for one small issue:

I have a lot of small functions that open a connection to the database (InnoDB engine), create a cursor, do insert / update operations, then .commit() the changes, .close() the cursor, then .close() the connection.  Sometimes there are multiple cursor creation/close cycles in the same function.  So far, not an issue.

However, some larger functions call several smaller functions -- each which may locally open their own connection, create their own cursor, commit their own changes, then close their own connection before returning.

Is there an accepted Python / Connector pattern for grouping transactions, i.e. demarking the start of a larger transaction where any subsequent calls to functions that call .commit() do NOTHING -- until that larger transaction is complete, and then all pending .commit() calls are allowed to complete?

Comment: As far as I know if you run in to an exception while in a transaction, it rolls back automatically... so I would think to just raise an exception where you want to `rollback()`.

Comment: @Renier -- could that be a feature of SQLAlchemy?  All my reading on SO and the web points to needing to proactively rollback() if a serious exception is thrown.